# Product rule for matrices, think of them as vectors or not?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am having difficulties interpreting an equality in a couple of lecture notes(http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Riemann.pdf).

It can be found on page $52$ and looks as follows,

$\frac{d}{dt}(df_{e^{tY_{I}}}(e^{tY_{I}}\cdot X_{I}))\mid_{t=0}=df_{I}^{2}(Y_{I},X_{I})+df_{I}(Y_{I}\cdot X_{I})$.

As for notation

$f:GL_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function defined locally around $I$

$Y_{I}$ and $X_{I}$ are tanget vectors at $I$

$e^{tY_{I}}$ represents a curve through $I$ with derivative $Y_{I}$ at $I$.

Clearly there is some sort of product rule at work, however I cannot make sense of it. I dont know if it is preferable to think of the objects as matrices or vectors to make things add up nicely, also I dont know how to think of the Hessian here as a function of two tangent vectors.

I seen some explanations which involves a connections but this is not introduced yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with Riemannian geometry; all that is needed is a systematic treatment of multivariable calculus. You are right, there is some sort of generalized product rule at play (which is a consequence of the multidimensional chain rule). For geometric insight it may help to think of them as tangent vectors, but to understand the differential calculus, it doesn't matter; what's more important is **a firm understanding of Linear Algebra** so that the following constructions are easy to digest. I highly recommend reading Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf), chapter $3$ in specific, for more details about everything I say (that's where most of my understanding came from).

First, we need to establish some preliminary notions. Let $V,W$ be real Banach spaces, and let $A$ be an open subset of $V$. For what follows, finite-dimensionality doesn't simplify any of the claims; but if you want to assume it, go ahead. Let $f:A \to W$ be a function. I assume you know what it means for $f$ to be (Frechet) differentiable at a point $\alpha \in A$ (otherwise, see Section 3.6). Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at every point of $A$. Then, we get a new function 
\begin{equation}
df: A \to L(V,W), \qquad \alpha \mapsto df_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
This new function is nothing too complicated; it is just a map from an open subset of a Banach space into another Banach space, so we can ask whether this function is differentiable at a point $\alpha \in A$. If it is, we denote its derivative at $\alpha$ by $d(df)_{\alpha} \equiv d^2f_{\alpha}$ ($\equiv$ just means they're different notations for same thing). Note the spaces which the second differential maps between, $d^2f_{\alpha}: V \to L(V,W)$, which means it is an element of $L\left(V, L(V,W) \right)$.

You asked how one can interpret "the hessian as a function of two tangent vectors". To do this, note that there is a natural isomorphism between $L(V, L(V,W))$, which is the space of linear maps from $V$ into $L(V,W)$, and $L^2(V;W)$, the space of bilinear maps from $V \times V$ into $W$. The isomorphism is given as follows: $\Phi: L(V,L(V,W)) \to L^2(V;W)$,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(T)[\xi, \eta] = \left(T(\xi) \right)(\eta)
\end{equation}
So the meaning of this is that $d^2f_{\alpha}$ is currently a linear function of one variable, and its output is a linear transformation, and hence it can "eat" another vector. This is "equivalent" to a new object, $\Phi(d^2f_{\alpha})$, which "eats" two vectors simultaneously and is bilinear. **Since the isomorphism $\Phi$ is so natural, we shall suppress it and abuse notation slightly, and switch back and forth between $d^2f_{\alpha}$, and $\Phi(d^2f_{\alpha})$, and denote them both as $d^2f_{\alpha}$ $^1$**.

Now that we have established what the second differential means and how to interpret it, we can proceed to the "generalised product rule" (which is really a special case of the chain rule) see Chapter $3$, Theorem $8.4$ for the proof. I'll state the theorem here (with slightly different notation).

> **Generalised Product Rule.** (Loomis and Sternberg Theorem $8.4$)
>
> Let $U,V,W, X$ be normed vector spaces. Let $g: U \to V$, and $h: U \to W $ be functions which are differentiable at a point $\beta \in U$. Let $\omega: V \times W \to X$ be a bounded bilinear map. With these assumptions, the composite function $F : U \to X$ defined by
>   \begin{equation}
> F(\xi) = \omega(g(\xi), h(\xi))
> \end{equation} 
>   is differentiable at $\beta$ and its derivative at $\beta$ (which is a linear map from $U$ into $X$) is given by the formula
>   \begin{align}
> dF_{\beta}(\cdot) = \omega(dg_{\beta}(\cdot), h(\beta)) + \omega(g(\beta), \tag{*}dh_{\beta}(\cdot)),
> \end{align}
>   i.e for all $x \in U$, we have
>   \begin{equation}
> dF_{\beta}(x) = \omega(dg_{\beta}(x), h(\beta)) + \omega(g(\beta), dh_{\beta}(x)).
> \end{equation}

In this theorem, we like to think of the bilinear map $\omega$ as a sort of "multiplication", so that $F(\xi)$ is the "product" of $g(\xi)$ and $h(\xi)$. Notice how the derivative is very similar to single variable: "differentiate the first, keep the second, $+$ keep the first, differentiate the second".

---

Finally, we can get to the actual derivative you're interested in. Here, in conformity to the notation of the theorem, we define the following maps:

- $\omega: L\left( M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R} \right) \times M_{n \times n}(R) \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $\omega(T, \xi) = T(\xi)$. So $\omega$ is like the "evaluation" map. You can easily check that it is bilinear (boundedness follows from the fact that the spaces are finite-dimensional)
- $g: \mathbb{R} \to M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, defined by $g(t) = e^{t Y_I}$.
- $h: \mathbb{R} \to M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, defined by $h(t) = e^{t Y_I} \cdot X_I$

With these "auxillary" maps defined, you can define the function you're really interested in:
\begin{align}
F(t) &= df_{g(t)}(h(t)) \\
&= \omega(df_{g(t)}, h(t))
\end{align}
(I hope you realise that $df_{g(t)}$ is convenient notation for $\left[(df) \circ g \right](t)$, and that subscripts just avoid more brackets.)
You now wish to compute $F'(0)$. Here's the general formula for $F'(t)$.
\begin{align}
F'(t) &= dF_t(1) \tag{Theorem $7.1$} \\
&= \omega \left( d\left( (df) \circ g\right)_t(1), h(t) \right) + \omega \left( df_{g(t)}, dh_t(1)\right) \tag{product rule} \\
&= \omega \left( [d^2f_{g(t)} \circ dg_t](1), h(t) \right) + \omega \left( df_{g(t)}, dh_t(1)\right) \tag{chain rule to $1^{st}$ term} \\
&= \omega \left( d^2f_{g(t)}[g'(t)], h(t) \right) + \omega \left( df_{g(t)}, h'(t)\right)
\tag{Theorem $7.1$} \\
&= \left( d^2f_{g(t)} \left[g'(t) \right] \right)[h(t)] + df_{g(t)}[h'(t)] \tag{defn of $\omega$} \\
& \equiv d^2f_{g(t)} \left[ g'(t), h(t) \right] + df_{g(t)}[h'(t)].
\end{align}
In the last line, I made the abuse of notation by suppressing the isomorphism $\Phi$. Substituting $t=0$, and using your knowledge of derivative of matrix exponentials will give you the desired answer.

With a bit of practice (such as the questions in Chapter 3 of the book), you'll be very comfortable with these manipulations, that it becomes unnecessary to explicitly write out the "auxillary" maps $\omega, g, h$ and you'll be directly able to apply the product rule to compute $F'(t)$.

---

[1.] For more about the second differential, see section $3.16$ of the book

Comment: thanks for answering,I do understand what "them" are in " For geometric insight it may help to think of them as tangent vectors" .

Comment: I was referring to $X_I$ and $Y_I$ as you did in your post

Comment: @user1 I said "in conformity to the notation of the theorem..." but actually the use of $g$ in the theorem and the use of $g$ in my work below are different...hopefully that's not too confusing.

Comment: should it not be $A$ and not $V$ 3rd paragraph last two lines. The domian of $df^{2}$

Comment: The domain of $d^2f$ is $A$, but when you evaluate this second differential at a point $\alpha \in A$, it's domain is $V$. So what I wrote is correct; $d^2f_{\alpha}$ maps $V$ into $L(V,W)$. This is just like how although the domain of $f$ is $A$, the domain of $df_{\alpha}$ is $V$, but the domain of $df$ is $A$

Comment: Can we say that in the same fashion the Jacobi matrix maps linear increments $h$ to new linear increments, we have the same for the second derivative only now iterated twice?

Comment: yes that's what's happening. (I'll omit $\Phi$ everywhere) $d^2f_{\alpha}$ takes in two increments $(\xi,\eta)$ in the domain $V\times V$, and bilinearly maps them to another increment $d^2f_{\alpha}(\xi, \eta)$ in the target space $W$. If you really want to, then you can associate $d^2f_{\alpha}$ with a matrix $H$, by defining $H_{ij} = d^2f_{\alpha}(e_i,e_j)$ (where the $e_i$'s form a basis of the underlying vector space $V$). Then you can think of all computations in terms of matrices (although once you get to $3rd$ derivatives it becomes a nightmare to keep track of all that info)